# Apache Ant gets frozen while running this script

Tags: java, javascript, swing, ant

I want to show a password input dialog from ant script. Here's my code from **build.xml**:

```
<target name="sign" unless="isUpToDate">
    <script language="javascript">
        importClass(javax.swing.JPasswordField);
        importClass(javax.swing.JOptionPane);
        var pf = new JPasswordField();
        var okCxl = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, pf, "Enter Password", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

        if (okCxl == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
            project.setNewProperty("keypass", pf.getPassword());
        } else {
            throw "Password is required";
        }
    </script>
    <echo message="${keypass}"></echo>
    ...
</target>
```

This code hangs forever. What's wrong?

**Update:**
I'm testing in Mac OS X 10.8.2 and Oracle JDK 7u13

Answer (score 1):

It works well in Eclipse  Juno Release Build id: 20120614-1722 and JDK 7 under Windows XP:

```
Buildfile: D:\...\build.xml
sign:
     [echo] [C@ea1569
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 7 seconds
```

And it works well from Run.bat :

```
D:\>call d:\ant\bin\ant
Buildfile: D:\...\build.xml

sign:
     [echo] [C@12a642

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 8 seconds
```

But [getPassword()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JPasswordField.html#getPassword%28%29) returns char[] not String, this is because the echo is not human readable.

Comment: I tried both Indigo and Juno, but it does not work for me. I'm on Mac OS X 10.8.2

Comment: Is Java in the PATH? Which version?

Comment: Oracle JDK 7u13, no troubles with PATH

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, put the `storepass` required by `<signjar />` in an invisible file, e.g. `.deployconf`, having user-only access: e.g. `400` or `600`. Load the password in `ant`, and use as required:

```
<loadfile srcfile="${user.home}/.deployconf" property="deployconf"/>
```

This works well with `<signjar />`, although some effort may be required to keep linefeeds out of `.deployconf`.